# Require child object property value to be same type as parent key

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, is it possible to enforce the following structure with an index signature?

```ts
{
    a: { name: 'a' }, // Valid
    b: { name: 'b' }, // Valid
    c: { name: 'd' } // Error: Type '"d"' is not assignable to type '"c"'.
}
```

The object accepts any number of properties, with any string key, but requires that the value of each property is an object, which itself has an optional 'name' property, the value of which must be the key to which it is assigned in the parent object.

It is possible to achieve something similar with a string union type, as follows. However, it's not clear how this can be extended to accept keys as any string.

```ts
type MethodNameVariant = 'GET' | 'PATCH' | 'POST' | 'DELETE';
type Methods =
{
    [MethodName in MethodNameVariant]?: Method <MethodName>
};
interface Method
{
    name?: MethodName;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

An index signature can't give you this behavior, since `string` has an infinite domain and can't easily be represented as a union of literal types the way, say, `boolean` [can](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22596#issuecomment-373722622).  TypeScript doesn't even attempt to iterate over `string` the way it does over unions of string literals in [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types); if you attempt it, you end up with the too-wide type `{[k: string]: {name: string}`.

The closest I can get to the desired behavior is to make a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) helper function to inspect the keys of any object type you give it, and then map over those keys.  Like so:

```
const asMyType = <T extends { [K in keyof T]: { name: K } }>(t: T) => t;
```

So `asMyType()` just returns its argument, but will only accept arguments that match your constraint.

```
const okay = asMyType({
  a: { name: "a" },
  b: { name: "b" },
  c: { name: "c" }
})

const notOkay = asMyType({
  a: { name: 'a' }, // Valid
  b: { name: 'b' }, // Valid
  c: { name: 'd' } // Error: Type '"d"' is not assignable to type '"c"'.
})
```

Good, that's the error you wanted!  The main drawback here is that `T extends {[K in keyof T]: ...` construct is not as easy to deal with as a plain old type, as it relies on generic type parameter inference, but depending on your use case it might work.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!